# How to enter delete confirmation state UITableViewCell from custom action?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

I have a problem, I want to show right delete confirmation button of my UITableView's cell. Swipe to delete works just fine but I also want this to happen without swiping.

I would like to change cell's state from default to showing delete confirmation. There is bool property showingDeleteConfirmation but it's read only.

```
 [self setEditing:YES animated:YES];
```

From custom cell's class doesn't do anything.

How to change cell's state to showing delete confirmation without swipe?

i.e. after swipe gesture on a cell is recognized what is being called? I would like to call it manually.

Comment: Just making sure I understand the question, if the UITableView were in Edit mode, showing circles on the left side. When one of those are selected, you want the user to confirm that they actually want that one deleted, correct?

Comment: NO, I mean when you SWIPE on a cell (like in messages app) -  on the right side delete button appears and the other cells remain on their default state. I would like that delete button to be appeared not only after swipe.

Answer (score 0):

That is a delegate method meaning you should not call it yourself as that is a part of the process handles by the tableView class.

Instead you'll want to override the call class, prepare the method to show your button (or whatever you want to show) and animate other views trimming their frames. Doing that you'll understand the difference between the delegate and instance messages as you'll probably need to notify the tableView or it's delegate that your method is complete, the button is shown and other views are also animated.